# Padding with Transposed convolution

Tags: conv-neural-network, transposed-convolution

I am wondering how padding affect transposed convolution, especially that a higher value for the padding makes the output smaller.

In the formula the term is -2 * padding.
So probably it is a substraction left and right, but how could I imagine it?

Comment: See this [blog post](http://makeyourownneuralnetwork.blogspot.com/2020/02/calculating-output-size-of-convolutions.html)

Comment: Thank you. I think I see how it works but need to give it a deeper look once more.
But what I realize is they introduce stride and padding at the same time, making it harder to differenciate only the padding does.